# Instagram: Signature did not match

Tags: python, instagram, instagram-api

I'm trying to get started with the Instagram API but I can't even make a simple call because I get an error

```
{"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "error_message": "Invalid signed-request: Signature does not match"}
```

I generated my `access_token` with scope as `likes+comments`.

This is my URL: 
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&sig=SIG

I generated the signature using this script from the Instagram developer site because it initially gave me

```
"Invalid signed-request: Missing required parameter 'sig'"
```

This is the script:

```
    # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
import hmac
from hashlib import sha256

def generate_sig(endpoint, params, secret):
    sig = endpoint
    for key in sorted(params.keys()):
        sig += '|%s=%s' % (key, params[key])
    return hmac.new(secret, sig, sha256).hexdigest()

endpoint = 'media/search'
params = {
    'access_token': _______________,
    'count': 10,
}
secret = ______________________
sig = generate_sig(endpoint, params, secret)
print "sig is",sig
```

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs:

> When enabled, Instagram will check for the *sig* parameter of each
>   request and verify that the value matches a hash computed using your
>   Client Secret. The expected value is a HMAC using the SHA256 hash
>   algorithm with **all your request parameters** and your Client Secret.

Your signature generator function is okay, but it is not includes all params. It should be:

```
params = {
    'access_token': _______________,
    'count': 10,
    'lat':  "<lat value>",
    'lng': "<long value>",
}
```

It should be work well.
Also, here is some helpful aditional guidelines:
http://instagram-api.tumblr.com/post/120586735719/instagram-secure-api-requests

## EDIT:

Here is exactly as I did:

```
# coding: utf-8

# My client_id, secret, access_token, etc...
import settings
from urllib import urlencode
import hmac
from hashlib import sha256

def generate_sig(endpoint, params, secret):
    sig = endpoint
    for key in sorted(params.keys()):
        sig += '|%s=%s' % (key, params[key])
    return hmac.new(secret, sig, sha256).hexdigest()


endpoint = '/media/search'
params = {
    'access_token': settings.ACCESS_TOKEN,
    'lat': '48.858844',
    'lng': '2.294351',
    'count': 10,
}
params.update({'sig': generate_sig(endpoint, params, settings.CLIENT_SECRET)})
url = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1' + endpoint + '?' + urlencode(params)

# Success!!!
print url
```

It should give us an URL like this format:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?access_token=XXX&lat=XXX&lng=XXX&sig=XXX&count=XXX
```

Comment: i think the `'count': 10` parameter should not be passed in the signature generation as its not present in the url.

As per the Insta doc - 

    > Token: API endpoint appended with a concatenation of all key/value pairs of your request parameters, sorted by key in ascending order. Each key/value pair is separated by the pipe character.

So either you add the count to your API request URL or remove it from the signature generation params, otherwise it will still give a "Invalid signed request" error!

Comment: @felipsmartins Thanks for the answer. I tried it but it still doesn't work. It gives me the same 'Invalid signed-request: Signature does not match' error.

Comment: @coderz I tried that as well. I removed it from the params and added it my URL as: https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=48.858844&lng=2.294351&access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN&sig=SIG&count=10. But, it still gives me the same error!

Comment: @Arjun Have you  enabled "Signed Requests"? Also, can you provide the full error message information?

Comment: @felipsmartins The error message was: 
{"code": 403, "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", "error_message": "Invalid signed-request: Signature does not match"}
Also, I unticked  'Enforce Signed Requests' and Now I am able to get the data.

Comment: @Arjun okay, I'll give a try later. BTW, there's some reason which you don't use the official client library? The official client library supports signed requests automatically.

Comment: @felipsmartins Do you mean this? https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram .. I started with it but decided that I can learn better about working with an API if I do it manually :)

Comment: @Arjun It works for me. Look my answer again, I've edited with snippet working code.

Comment: @felipsmartins Thank you so much! It works well.. could you tell me what I was doing wrong though?

Comment: @Arjun If you've been getting "Invalid signed-request: Signature does not match" it means values encoded and sent to request was wrong. Just compare my snippet code to your code.